# Override knowledge auto suggest

Tags: knowledge

Is it possible to override the knowledge auto suggest? Currently the knowledge auto suggests an article based on the case's subject. How can I modify and make it based on a custom field on Account. Thanks

Comment: Is that below answer solved your problem? If yes, please mark so that others can find it suitable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use controller extension of ApexPages.KnowledgeArticleVersionStandardController as follows:

```
public class AgentContributionArticleController{
// The constructor must take a ApexPages.KnowledgeArticleVersionStandardController as an argument
public AgentContributionArticleController(ApexPages.KnowledgeArticleVersionStandardController ctl) 
{
    SObject article = ctl.getRecord(); //this is the SObject for the new article.
    //It can optionally be cast to the proper   article type, e.g. 
    //FAQ__kav article = (FAQ__kav) ctl.getRecord();  

    String sourceId = ctl.getSourceId(); //this returns the id of the case that was closed.     
    Account acct = [SELECT Custom_Field__c From Account WHERE Id IN (SELECT AccountId from Case where id=:sourceId)];       
    article.put('title', acct.Custom_Field__c);       
}
}
```

In the **Knowledge settings**, be sure to add this class for this settings: **Use APEX customization** under **Case Settings**

Comment: @gelay, Please mark the answer if it solves your problem